# Why are GAN models not heavily used for NLP?

Tags: natural-language-processing, generative-adversarial-networks

I am wondering why there has not been more usage of GANs for NLP. I know there has been research on the subject (The Google Scholar page for the subject is [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=GANs+for+nlp&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart)).

Are there any specific reasons why GANs do not work for NLP specifically VQGAN + CLIP variants? I do not understand why most text generated by AI is done through predicting the next letter or word in a sequence with RNNs when GANs have had so much success generating deep fakes and the such instead of say, predicting the next pixel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few reasons:

1. Transformers are amazing at text generation already (e.g. [GPT-3](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.14165) which [almost passes](https://lacker.io/ai/2020/07/06/giving-gpt-3-a-turing-test.html) the [Turing-Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test))
2. [The original GAN requires a continuous data representation](https://www.quora.com/Can-one-use-generative-adversarial-networks-in-NLP-related-problems) (e.g. images) instead of a discrete one (e.g. text), so that slight error signals can be used for learning.
3. Empirically speaking, GANs don't seem to work that well on non-image data. I recently applied them to regular tabular data but found auto-encoders much more useful.

P.S. Also it's my intuition that GAN's and [Denoising Diffusion Models](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2020/file/4c5bcfec8584af0d967f1ab10179ca4b-Paper.pdf) are popular in the *image generation community* because they both offer mechanisms that can [**prevent "blurriness"**](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/8885/why-is-the-variational-auto-encoders-output-blurred-while-gans-output-is-crisp) in the generated images (either the adversary or extra denoising iterations).

Comment: Please, remove the very arguable sentence "which essentially passes the Turing-Test". Alternatively, can you provide some real evidence for it? If it generates some meaningful text it doesn't mean passed the Turing test. I'm sure it doesn't pass the imitation game.

Comment: I edited it to include a reference, and say 'almost passes' since it still isn't great at answering nonsense questions.

Comment: I should mention however that when GPT-3 is primed with examples (via meta-learning) of calling out nonsense it does learn the skill immediately: https://arr.am/2020/07/25/gpt-3-uncertainty-prompts/